# Insertar una gran cantidad de registros en cassandra

Tags: java, base-de-datos, cassandra

Necesito insertar 1 millón de registros en cassandra, estoy usando el driver de `datastax`, cuento con una clase profesor correctamente mapeada y una lista de profesores, luego mediante el mapper llamo al método save.

```
Cluster cluster  = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("MiServer").build();
    Session session = cluster.connect("prueba");
    Mapper<Profesor> mapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(Profesor.class);
    List<Profesor> profesors = CSVLogic.readAll("data.csv");
    profesors.forEach(mapper::save);
```

la inserción funciona bien sin embargo el rendimiento no me parece bueno, y quiero saber cuál es la forma mas eficiente para insertar 1 millón de registros desde java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El rendimiento suele aumentar si vamos a más bajo nivel, quizá puedas usar algo como [BatchStatement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/index.html?com/datastax/driver/core/BatchStatement.html) y agrupar muchos PreparedStatement. El código sería algo como:

```
PreparedStatement statement= session.prepare("INSERT INTO people (name,age) VALUES (?,?)");
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
BatchStatement batchStmt = new BatchStatement();
batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind("User A", "10"));
batchStmt.add(boundStatement.bind("User B", "12"));
session.execute(batchStmt);
```

Con un bucle podrías meter todos los datos (o en grupos de unos cuantos miles, al menos).

La idea la he tomado de una pregunta similar en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885238/how-to-multi-insert-rows-in-cassandra)

Comment: Funciona fantásticamente, Muchas Gracias